# Adaptar proyecto de android studio a múltiples pantallas

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

El problema es el siguiente estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto pero quiero ajustarlo para que se vea bien en varios tamaño de pantalla , cuando creo el archivo `xml` con el tamaño en `dp` definido , en el `prewiew` se ve bien pero cuando ejecuto el emulador no se ve bien .

¿Qué otro método existe ?

En esta imagen se e que en el preview se ve bien el layout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca en el emulador da este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Échale un vistazo a la documentación de android respecto al soporte de diferentes tipos de pantallas. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=es-419

Comment: Ya ese artículo lo leí e implemente , agregué varias imágenes del problema que es que tengo que en preview se ve bien pero en el emulador no se adapta

Comment: ¿Estas usando el mismo tipo de pantalla en el emulador y en la preview?

Comment: si estoy usando la de nexus 5x

Comment: Prueba a conectar los elementos entre si y conectarlos también a los bordes del layout, de esta forma fijaras que un determinado elemento tenga que estar siempre a una distancia X de otro y a una distancia Y del borde de la pantalla. Haciendo esto te debería funcionar y respetar la distribución. Espero que te sirva, un saludo!!